# need some help getting powershell do delete cell content and inserting a formula

Tags: excel, powershell

Here is the script as it sits. `$of` is set to the name of the file that gets downloaded with `wget`. I am getting exception from `HRESULT: 0x0800A03EC` which has something to do with the range portion and it seeing a 0 based range, but I am giving it 2 : # of rows.

How can I get PowerShell to clear the range and then insert the formula?

```
#open the downloaded worksheet
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($of)
$page = 'Project Summary'
$ws = $Workbook.Worksheets | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $page}

# Set variables for the worksheet cells, and for navigation
$cells = $ws.Cells
$row = 1
$col = 5

# Add the header to the worksheet
$headers = "Region"
$headers | foreach {
    $cells.Item($row, $col) = $_
}

# Add the formula to each occupied row
$rows = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

$ws.Range("E2:E" + $rows).Clear()
$ws.Range("E2:E" + $rows).Formula = "=SUM(E2:E5)"

$Excel.Visible = $true

$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs('W:\test.xlsx')
```

I also tried

```
$rows | foreach {
    $ws.Cells("E" + $rows).Clear()
    $ws.Cells("E" + $rows).Formula = "=SUM(E2:E5)"
}
```

That gives me a Value does not fall within the expected range error.

How can I get this to clear each cell in the range `E2:E<lastRow>` and then insert a formula?

I have gone back to the following after finding a way to escape the entire formula using `@' ... '@`; there was clearly an error in my escape sequence earlier, but the following is not performing exactly as expected either.

```
$ws.Range("E2:E$rows").Clear();
$ws.Range("E2:E$rows").Formula = $Formula1
```

This now populates the formula, but it comes in as text and not as a formula; I have to solve for this.

Comment: Have many cells do you intend to change. Your tried code will attempt to change one. Are you trying to loop through all used rows in column E?

Comment: Did you ever hear of [PSExcel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel)?

Comment: `$ws.Cells.Item(2,5).Formula` another question here tried the following to change a cells formula.

Comment: I intend to change all the cells from E2 until Last row used row in E.  No, never heard of PSExcel.

Comment: except he is only adding a formula to one cell.  So maybe I need to modify that $ws.Cells.item(5,$rows) = .... and use that with the for each.  I also don't know why that didn't come up when I searched on google >.<

Comment: $rows = $worksheet.Range("E1").Rows.Count 

while($i -ne $rows) {
 $ws.Cells.item(5,$rows).Clear()
 $ws.Cells.item(5,$rows) = '=SUM(E2:E5)'
 $i++
}

loops, but gives the same Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: How about `2..$rows | ForEach{$ws.cells.item("E$_").Clear();$ws.cells.item("E$_").Formula="=SUM(E2:E5)"}`

Comment: The loop is not the problem you are having. It seems that you need to enter a single formula properly. Adding loop logic should not be too difficult. Dupes do not need to be 100% _perfect_ to be useful.

Comment: in your example you are looping while tracking the index `$i` but you never use that index when calling the changes. Same issue you have in the question. TheMadTechnician gives a working example in comments

Comment: I am still getting the Values does not fall within the expected range using MadTech's loop.  Which I was getting with my second loop.  I entered the formula different after reading the post you pointed out using @" .... "@

Comment: `$rows = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` -> `$rows = $ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: Ansgar, yes I caught that when I caught the escape sequence issue after matt point at the other post.  Thanks for also pointing it out.

Comment: There is no `$Formula1` in the code you posted before. If you want us to help you need to post a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the problem, including the full error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #open the downloaded worksheet
    $Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
    $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($of)
    $page = 'Project Summary'
    $ws = $Workbook.Worksheets | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $page}

    # Set variables for the worksheet cells, and for navigation
    $cells = $ws.Cells
    $row = 1
    $col = 5

    # Add the header to the worksheet
    $headers = "Region"
   #open the downloaded worksheet
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($of)
$page = 'Project Summary'
$ws = $Workbook.worksheets | where-object {$_.Name -eq $page}
$Formula1 = @"
=SUM(E2:E5)
"@
$cells=$ws.Cells
$row=1
$col=5
$range = $ws.UsedRange
$rows = $range.Rows.Count 

$ws.Range("E2:E$rows").Clear();
$ws.Range("E2:E$rows").Formula = $Formula1

# Add the header to the worksheet
$headers = "Region"
$headers | foreach {
  $cells.item($row, $col) = $_
} 

$excel.visible = $true

$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs('W:\Test.xlsx')
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)

Remove-Item $of
```

This is the outcome.  Escaping may or may not have been the original issue, but the help here guided me to a better way to deal with it if it was the issue.  I still never solved why the loop was giving the value error, but this works so I won't have to tackle that yet; that is the next script which this post will also help me with.